# get timestamp (date and time) from sd card file

Tags: basic4android

Hello out there in B4A world!  I'm trying to retrieve the timestamp from a file on the sd card.  The function 'files' doesn't have a timestamp method but I see the usage of things like file timestamp in ftp operations.  What am I missing?!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [File.LastModified](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/files.html#file_lastmodified) to get the timestamp.
I think that this method was added in B4A v1.5 or v1.6.

Comment: Thanks Erel, I am using that method, I must be doing something else wrong in my code using the DateTime.Date function.